# How to get this filter to go in order (brand one starting with A all items, then two etc) Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hi Im using a plugin to make brands available on the website, I've added a code snippet to add this into my sorting method:

```
function theme_catalog_orderby( $catalog_orderby_options ) {
    $catalog_orderby_options['brands'] = __( 'Sort by brands', 'textdomain' );
 
    return $catalog_orderby_options;
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'theme_catalog_orderby' );

/**
* Returns an array of arguments for ordering products based on the selected values.
*
* @uses woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args hook
* @return array
*/
function theme_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'sale' == $orderby_value ) {
 
        $args['meta_key'] = '_product_attribute[pa_brands]';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
 
    }
 
    return $args;
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'theme_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
```

However even though its displaying the brands I want it to go by brand starting with A -> Z so a brand Alls will have all Alls first show up then lets say theres no B so Cats brand all show up

Comment: Why are you using `meta_value_num`, when you want to order by alphanumeric values? Why `DESC`, when you want A-Z and not Z-A?

Comment: Ah thanks for that! So i'd apply 'title

Comment: Thought would this be able to then group the brands ?

Comment: So tried the filtering but its still not working as intended by switching to title and ASC